# icon in component header is not showing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am following the [doc example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html) here to add a plus + to component header:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { SectionList, View, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform, TouchableHighlight, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {Icon } from "react-native-elements";

export default class Event extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
      console.log("in event header");
      return {
        headerTitle: 'Event',
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Icon 
              name="plus" 
              size={30} 
              type='octicon' 
              onPress={navigation.getParam('navToNewEvent')}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        };
    }

    _navToNewEvent = () => {
      console.log("Route to new event");
      this.props.navigation.navigate("NewEvent");
    };

    async componentDidMount(){
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ navToNewEvent: this._navToNewEvent })
    ....
    }
```

However the `plus +` is not showing in component header:

[image]

What is missing in my code above?

UPDATE: the navigation code before component `Event` is:

```
return createBottomTabNavigator(
          {
            Event: {screen: EventStack},
            Group: {screen: GroupStack},
            Contact: {screen: ContactStack},

          }, bottomTabNavOptions
      );

const bottomTabNavOptions =  {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      console.log("route name", routeName);
      let iconName;
      if (routeName === 'Event') {
        iconName = `list-unordered`;
      } else if (routeName === 'NewEvent') {
        iconName = "kebab-horizontal";
      } else if (routeName === 'NewUser') {
        iconName = `person`;
      } else if (routeName === 'ListUser') {
        iconName = `organization`
      }

      return <Icon name={iconName} size={30} color={tintColor} type='octicon' />;
    },
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  },
};

const EventStack = createStackNavigator({

      Event:  {
        screen: EventWithSelf,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Event',
        },
      },
      NewEvent: {
        screen: NeweventWithSelf,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'New Event',
        },
      },

      EditEvent: {
        screen: EditEventWithSelf,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Edit Event',
        },
      },

      Chat: {
        screen: ChatWithSocket,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Chat',
        },

      },     
    });
```

Comment: You must move up the `onPress={() => navigation.getParam('navToNewEvent')}` to `TouchableOpacity`, also try to add color to your Icon.

Comment: I commented out the `onPress` and the plus sign still no show.

Comment: Have you tried to add color?

Comment: color = {tintColor} did not do anything. The plus sign is still no show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply looking at the code doesn't seem wrong. There is one catch. Would you like to modify this?

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
      console.log("in event header");
      return {
        title: 'Event',
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Icon 
              name="plus" 
              size={30} 
              type='octicon' 
              onPress={() => navigation.getParam('navToNewEvent')}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        };
    }
```

You can use `defaultNavigationOptions`
The Event tab you represent is not a single screen. As a common header, configure the title and button in defaultNavigationOptions.

```js
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
...
 headerTitle: 'Event',
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Icon 
              name="plus" 
              size={30} 
              type='octicon' 
              onPress={navigation.getParam('navToNewEvent')}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
```

Comment: Either way for calling getParam is fine according to the document. The issue is that the plus sign is not showing up.

Comment: I tried changing the code. Would you like to try this?

Comment: The issue is no show of the icon. There is no difference after change calling pattern for onPress.. Both call patterns are presented in the official document.. I commented out the whole onPress and there is no difference either.

Comment: @user938363 I changed name `headerTitle` => `title`

Comment: @user938363 Can I see your Navigator setup file code?

Comment: Just added navigation code for reference. Tested a simple <Text> or <Button> and is still no show.

Comment: @user938363  The Event tab you represent is not a single screen. As a common header, configure the title and button in defaultNavigationOptions.

Comment: The defaultNavigationOptions is ignored and was not updated when `Event` is rendered.. What the app needs to do  is when `Event` component is rendered,  add a clickable plus sign to the header right. The place which can do this is within the `EventStack` definition in `App.js`. The question is how to make the app do it in `Event` component.

Comment: @user938363 Isn't your question a question that the icon doesn't appear? Like my answer, you can see a plus icon.

Comment: I made my answer an example myself. https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/bottom-navigation-example?session_id=snack-session-CxUjYtYnj